# EF Code First CTP5, using Include method with Many to Many table

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

I have something like the following many to many relationship tables.

```
public class Shop{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<ShopFacility> ShopFacilities { get; set; }
}

public class ShopFacility
{
 public int Id { get; set; }        
 public int ShopId { get; set; }
 public int FacilityId { get; set; }
 public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }
 public virtual Facility Facility { get; set; }
}

public class Facility
{
 public int Id { get; set; }        
 public virtual ICollection<ShopFacility> ShopFacilities { get; set; }
}
```

and, get shops information.

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
 return context.Shops.Include(s => s.ShopFacilities)
                     .Include("ShopFacilities.Facility")  // This line
                     .First(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

What I want to do is call the Include method with a Lambda expression for a many to many relationship instead of string. I've tried to implement like the below code:

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
 return context.Shops.Include(s => s.ShopFacilities)
                     .Include(s => s.ShopFacilities.Facility)  // Cannot compile
                     .First(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

But as you guess I cannot compile it. Actually, the first code snippet works well, so basically it's okay, though, I'm kinda curious whether there is a work around or not.

Any help would be appreciated,

Yoo

Comment: Just wanted to say that you don't really need the ShopFacility class. Your Shop class can have an `ICollection<Facility>` and your Facility class can have an `ICollection<Shop>`. EF Code First will understand that you need a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: I know the EF Code first is pretty much smart, but actually ShopFacility has some other properties such as comment, fee and so on, so I have to have it. My apologies not to mention it. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
return context.Shops.Include(s => s.ShopFacilities.Select(f => f.Facility))
              .First(x => x.Id == id);
```

But you should follow what @Kristof suggested in comment.

Comment: The strongly typed `Include()` method is an extension method so you have to remember to declare the `using System.Data.Entity;` statement.