# EF 4.1, Code-First: Eager loading of cascading collections

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

If I have the following class model ...

```
public class A
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> BCollection { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<C> CCollection { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int CId { get; set; }
}
```

... is it possible to eager-load an object of type `A` from the database with all cascading collections included?

I can include the `BCollection` like so:

```
A a = context.ASet.Where(x => x.AId == 1)
          .Include(x => x.BCollection)
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Can I also include somehow the `CCollection` of all loaded `B` objects so that I get `A` with all dependent objects in memory with a single database query?

Comment: I started this question on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-use-version-specific-tags It is related to our previous communication about version specific tags in EF.

Comment: @Ladislav: OK, I'll watch this. Let's see how the veterans think about it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `.Include(x => x.BCollection.Select(b => b.CCollection))` also [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247324/ef-code-first-ctp5-using-include-method-with-many-to-many-table).

It works also for cascade. Every time you need to eager load navigation property which is collection use `.Select`.

Comment: Thanks! And for even deeper hierarchies I simply chain the Selects, like so: `.Include(x => x.BCollection.Select(b => b.CCollection.Select(c => c.DCollection)))`, right?

Comment: @Slauma Yes, but the chained select must be the only item the firsrt select. You cannot select a single entity and a collection at the same time. Bad e.g.: .Include(x => x.BCollection.Select(b => new { b.ChildEntity, b.CCollection.Select(c => c.DCollection) }))